# Autofilter: Range class failure on "<>" within the code's generated arrays for the criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofilter

My code reads the values of cells within 3 column until it meets an empty cell and fills 3 arrays with the values. I use `<>` when I don't want to filter through a column or `<>item` if I want all but the one.

The problem is that if an array contains the negation symbol, it says the Range class has failed. However, if I straight up write `<>` / `<>Item` into criteria it goes through. Same if I use `Criteria1:=array(filter1, filter2,...)` and either of the "filter" values has one or both of the two options. Just when I do `Criteria1:=arrayName` it fails. Importantly, it does not fail when it simply just contains "Item". It also does not fail when I write it in as `Criteria:=arrayName(1)`, and the index one (first) contains the negation.
I'm failing to get my head around what is going on. Sorry if the answer is trivial.

```vb
Dim sel As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim distri() As String
Dim purp() As String
Dim prod() As String

'user selects a value in the workbook, the value is found in another workbook
'There are then criterias in 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns by which sheet "data" is filtered by
sel = Selection.Value
Windows("different_workbook.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("values").Select

Cells.Find(What:=sel, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Let selCol = Selection.Column
Let selRow = Selection.Row
Sheets("calculations").Select
Cells(selRow, selCol).Select
Let end = False
i = 0
While end = False 'going through the criteria top > down until there is a space between the criterias, some values need multiple filtered items
    If IsEmpty(Cells(selRow + i, 2).Value) Or IsEmpty(Cells(selRow + i, 3).Value) Or IsEmpty(Cells(selRow + i, 4).Value) Then
        end = True
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Wend 'now the code knows how many criterias to expect
ReDim Preserve distri(1 To i)
ReDim Preserve purp(1 To i)
ReDim Preserve prod(1 To i)
For j = 1 To i
    distri(j) = Cells(selRow + j - 1, 2).Value
    purp(j) = Cells(selRow + j - 1, 3).Value
    prod(j) = Cells(selRow + j - 1, 4).Value
Next
Sheets("data").Select 'the three commands where the error occurs
ActiveSheet.Rows(3).AutoFilter Field:=4, _
Criteria1:=distri, _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Rows(3).AutoFilter Field:=5, _
Criteria1:=purp, _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Rows(3).AutoFilter Field:=8, _
Criteria1:=prod, _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I'm expecting it to use `<>` as "passes" for filtration. It did work for me in my older code, where I hard coded which line has how many rows of criteria, each of the criteria I saved into a variable and then made the `:=array(filter1,..)` example. Now I decided to make it a more flexible macro and easier to read and shorter code etc.

Comment: I do not get an error with string representation of negative numbers stored in the criteria array. You must have some other type of unsupported value in those cells.

Comment: First off, thanks for the edits and sorry for so many of mine, I wrote this yesterday hastly before i had to go, so now i'm putting on patches, like translations etc. Second, the types. The arrays and values in them are all String type. If I call first value of an array which contains the troubled `<>` or `<>Item` it does filter. However if I call the entire array, even if it contains only one values and it is of those two, it throws me the error. Thirdly, if an array contains a normal word, it filters by the word, despite it is not a word the column even contains.

Comment: `Criteria1:=distri(1)` works; `Criteria1:="<>Item"` works; `Criteria1:=distri` does not work if it contains `<>` or `<>Item`, `Criteria1:=distri`WORKS if it contains essentially any word without  `<>`. Also`Criteria1:=array(filter1, filter2..)` works everytime.

Comment: `xlFilterValues` is for a list of values to keep, not for comparisons. If you want comparisons, that would be `xlAnd` or `xlOr`, and you can only have at most two. Setting the `xlFilterValues` array is unchecking certain entries from the [filter dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdMxX.png), you cannot provide an expression there.

Comment: Removing `xlFilterValues` did help! But, now when my array contains multiple values to filter by, it only uses the last one, haha. I think I can make a condition around it, althought it is not very elegant, any ideas? :)

Comment: Im guessing using `xlAnd` and `xlOr` would do the trick for me, however if I were in need of use of more than two filters I'm screwed unless I would use more heavy handed code overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a bit of help by @GSerg who really made me realize how Autofilter works I figured out a work around the annoying fact you can't add comparisons while using `xlFilterValues`.
 Since using `<>` and `<>Item` are both vital for me and in MY case they always repeats in their respective column if there is more than criteria for other columns (there never is (`<>Item1`, `<>Item2`...) only  (`<>Item1`, `<>Item1`...) but there can be (`Item1`, `Item2`...) this code works perfectly, hopefully a soul in the future finds this useful:

```
    'this replaces the troubled part, the rest remains the same as in the original post
    If Left(distri(1), 2) = "<>" Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(3).AutoFilter Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=distri(1)
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Rows(3).AutoFilter Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=distri, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If Left(purp(1), 2) = "<>" Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(3).AutoFilter Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:=purp(1)
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Rows(3).AutoFilter Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:=purp, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If Left(prod(1), 2) = "<>" Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(3).AutoFilter Field:=8, _
        Criteria1:=prod(1)
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Rows(3).AutoFilter Field:=8, _
        Criteria1:=prod, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If
```